# Gradle test: how to do something even if the tests fail

Tags: gradle

My current test task looks like this:

```
test {
    doFirst {
        println 'Starting application...'
        Thread.startDaemon {
            appProcess = testServerExec.execute()
        }
        sleep 20000 // wait for thread to start
    }

    doLast {
        appProcess.destroy()
    }
}
```

I've noticed that if the tests pass, `appProcess.destroy()` is called and everyone's happy. However, if the tests fail, the thread lingers and I have to kill the process myself. I know Gradle has a try/finally, but I'm not sure how to use that correctly in this case. Basically, I want `appProcess.destroy()` to run, even if tests fail.

How might I go about it?

Edit: Discovered `beforeSuite` and `afterSuite`, but I run multiple suites of tests and I only want this thread started before all suites, and killed after all suites.

Comment: I'm not an expert, but have you tried `afterTest`? It seems to be a tear down capability. [doc](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/testing/Test.html#afterTest(groovy.lang.Closure))

Comment: There are multiple tests in multiple suites, and I only want this thread created/destroyed once, so `afterTest` and `afterSuite` won't work for me. It's a good thought, though.

Comment: Can you then make use of [source sets](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/userguide_single.html#N11D51)?

Comment: In Gradle 1.7 and beyond, [finalizer tasks](http://www.gradle.org/docs/release-candidate/release-notes#finalizer-tasks) are the way to go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use afterSuite and check for the suite with null parent. This is the root suite:

```
test{
    afterSuite{descr, result ->
        if(desc.parent == null){
            //put your logic here
        }
    }
}
```

hope that helps,

cheers, René

Comment: Works well. Looks like this'll hold me off until Gradle 1.7 with the finalizers. Thanks!